# What is the use of "Padding" in "render to texture" dialog ? And Also what kind of selected object settings are "Enabled"?

Tags: 3dsmax

I am new to 3ds max please help me here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi according to the documentation this indicate "The amount, in pixels, that edges are allowed to overlap in the flattened (“unwrapped”) texture. Default=2 pixels.
If the baked texture shows visible seams when you view it in shaded viewports or renderings, try increasing this value."

You should be able to find answer to most of your question in there: http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-3C2E6410-AD78-42D0-B4FC-CA6E2B1EF718

Otherwise, if you have the chance to have access to a more recent version of 3ds Max, I would recommend taking a look at the new bake to Texture tool.
See this link for more information:
https://area.autodesk.com/tutorials/series/3ds-max-2021-bake-to-texture-1/